# Какой способ предпочтительней для работы с ADO.NET

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Вопрос к опытным разработчикам. Собираюсь писать диплом с использованием технологии ADO.NET
В ходе изучение материала увидел разнообразие методов для работы с БД.
Подскажите какой из методов наиболее предпочтительней: 
 1. Самый изимод, добавить источник данных в проект, связать необходимые компоненты (comboBox, DataGridView) с данными непосредственно на этапе проектирования, появится BindingNavigator, есть кнопки добавления, удаления, итп... 
 2. Руками создать в коде объект DataSet, опять же руками выгружать посредством класса DataAdapter данные из источника данных в DataSet, там же связывать компоненты итд...
 3. Ну и этот вариант я использовать побаиваюсь, хотя не исключаю его: использовать Entity Framework вместе с LINQ to Entity.
Подскажите пожалуйста, основываясь на своём опыте....
 Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Вообще-то третий вариант и есть тот самый изимод. Работать с `EF` одно удовольствие (ну почти одно).

Такой вопрос, а выбрав первый вариант Вы куда потом данные сохраняете? Если Вы будете юзать `EF` всё равно придется делать привязку :)

И да, переходите уже на `wpf`

Comment: В каком плане куда?) Вообще база MySql... В 1 - ом варианте кнопка Save сама создается. Генерируется метод Update объекта DataAdapter

Comment: А магия, понятно :)
Работа с `ef` прозрачна и удобна: создали модельки, создали репозиторий на форме привязались к репозиторию (используя тот же `BindingSource`) и готово.